# Python pandas make new column from data in existing column and from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame called 'mydata', and if I do

```
len(mydata.loc['2015-9-2'])
```

It counts the number of rows in mydata that have that date, and returns a number like

```
1067
```

I have another DataFrame called 'yourdata' which looks something like

```
     timestamp
51   2015-06-22
52   2015-06-23
53   2015-06-24
54   2015-06-25
43   2015-07-13
```

Now I want use each date in yourdata so instead of typing in each date

```
len(mydata.loc['2015-9-2'])
```

I can iterate through 'yourdata' using them like

```
len(mydata.loc[yourdata['timestamp']])
```

and produce a new DataFrame with the results or just add a new column to yourdata with the result for each date, but I'm lost as how to do this?

The following does not work

```
yourdata['result'] = len(mydata.loc[yourdata['timestamp']])
```

neither does this

```
yourdata['result'] = len(mydata.loc[yourdata.iloc[:,-3]])
```

this does work

```
yourdata['result'] = len(mydata.loc['2015-9-2'])
```

buts that no good as I want to use the date in each row not some fixed date.

**Edit**: first few rows of mydata

```
    timestamp            BPM
 0  2015-08-30 16:48:00   65
 1  2015-08-30 16:48:10   65
 2  2015-08-30 16:48:15   66
 3  2015-08-30 16:48:20   67
 4  2015-08-30 16:48:30   70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2015-06-22 16:48:00']*3 +
                                    ['2015-06-23 16:48:00']*2 +
                                    ['2015-06-24 16:48:00'] +
                                    ['2015-06-25 16:48:00']*4 +
                                    ['2015-07-13 16:48:00',
                                     '2015-08-13 16:48:00'],
                       'BPM': [65]*8 + [70]*4})
mydata['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(mydata['timestamp'])
print(mydata)

#     BPM           timestamp
# 0    65 2015-06-22 16:48:00
# 1    65 2015-06-22 16:48:00
# 2    65 2015-06-22 16:48:00
# 3    65 2015-06-23 16:48:00
# 4    65 2015-06-23 16:48:00
# 5    65 2015-06-24 16:48:00
# 6    65 2015-06-25 16:48:00
# 7    65 2015-06-25 16:48:00
# 8    70 2015-06-25 16:48:00
# 9    70 2015-06-25 16:48:00
# 10   70 2015-07-13 16:48:00
# 11   70 2015-08-13 16:48:00

yourdata = pd.Series(['2015-06-22', '2015-06-23', '2015-06-24',
                      '2015-06-25', '2015-07-13'], name='timestamp')
yourdata = pd.to_datetime(yourdata).to_frame()
print(yourdata)

# 0   2015-06-22
# 1   2015-06-23
# 2   2015-06-24
# 3   2015-06-25
# 4   2015-07-13

result = (mydata.set_index('timestamp').resample('D')
                .size().loc[yourdata['timestamp']]
                .reset_index())
result.columns = ['timestamp', 'result']
print(result)

#    timestamp  result
# 0 2015-06-22       3
# 1 2015-06-23       2
# 2 2015-06-24       1
# 3 2015-06-25       4
# 4 2015-07-13       1
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives the error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @RunnerBean: try now.

Comment: no difference, I cant even see how youve change the code it looks the same as before

Comment: With the second one I get this error: ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Comment: for the first approach i get the error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Could you post a few rows of `mydata` in your question? Also, which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce the `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key` by running the second snippet after the first one. Notice that you have to run one *or* the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118241/discussion-between-runner-bean-and-alberto-garcia-raboso).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), but first convert to dates by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), convert to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and last use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (yourdata.join(pd.to_datetime(mydata.timestamp.dt.date)
                       .value_counts()
                       .rename('len'), on='timestamp'))
```

Sample:

```
print (mydata)
             timestamp  BPM
0  2015-06-23 16:48:00   65
1  2015-06-23 16:48:10   65
2  2015-06-23 16:48:15   66
3  2015-06-23 16:48:20   67
4  2015-06-22 16:48:30   70

print (yourdata)
     timestamp
51  2015-06-22
52  2015-06-23
53  2015-06-24
54  2015-06-25
43  2015-07-13

#if dtype not datetime
mydata['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(mydata['timestamp'])
yourdata['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(yourdata['timestamp'])

print (yourdata.join(pd.to_datetime(mydata.timestamp.dt.date)
                       .value_counts()
                       .rename('len'), on='timestamp'))
    timestamp  len
51 2015-06-22  1.0
52 2015-06-23  4.0
53 2015-06-24  NaN
54 2015-06-25  NaN
43 2015-07-13  NaN
```